# Capturar dados até o espaço, regex

Tags: regex

Estou usando esta expressão regular para capturar dados entre asteriscos:

```
\*(.+)\*
```

contudo ela captura de forma errônea quando o texto se enche de asteriscos, por exemplo em:

```
oi pessoas *lindas* e pessoas *lindos*
```

ela entende apenas os asteriscos mais de fora capturando todo o `lindas* e pessoas *lindos` sendo que era para capturar apenas `lindas` e `lindos` separadamente.

Existe alguma forma de adapta-la para que ela pegue de forma separada? Usando alguma condição com espaço ou algo assim..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode utilizar o `\w+` para indicar que existem apenas letras entre os asteriscos:

a expressão: `\*(\w+)\*`

[veja funcionando no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4oRHpi/1)

Comment: https://regexr.com/3kvab para o caso de tudo (números e letras)

Comment: teria como ao invés de especificar o que eu quero, especificar o que eu não gostaria? Tipo deixar tudo menos espaço

Comment: @user3163662 Sim. Basta adicionar `^` dentro dos colchetes.